# Why does solana uses only half of the private key to sign using ed25519?

Tags: private-key, ed25519

```
var sign = function sign(message, secretKey) {
  return ed25519.ed25519.sign(message, secretKey.slice(0, 32));
};
```

This is what the official `@solana/web3.js` library does to sign a transaction.
Is this because ed25519 is limited to 32-bytes or even other blockchains are using only half of the private key? What are the benefits of having a 64-bytes private key if only half of it is necessary to sign any transaction?

Answer (score 3):

Without getting too into the weeds, Ed25519 signing uses both the public key and the private key.

The 64 bytes you see in the `Keypair` class of `@solana/web3.js` is actually the `Ed25519` key-pair. The first half is the *seed* used to derive the private scalar and the second half is the actual public key itself.

In fact, if you convert the second half of the key-pair bytes into a base58 string, you'll get your Solana address!

`@solana/web3.js` doesn't need to pass both keys to the `ed25519` library since that library uses the seed to derive both the private scalar *and* the public key.

https://github.com/paulmillr/noble-curves/blob/7f851873f97e55b7e4e46457c268f61400887ba3/src/abstract/edwards.ts#L448

As far as your specific question as to *why* they're included together in the first place, this was likely a design choice made by engineers for a few possible reasons, including:

- compatibility with libraries who expect the 64-byte format
- increased performance (don't need to compute the public key from the seed)
- possibly others